# Hibernate naming strategy for indexes to prevent too long identifiers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a root entity (inheritance is `TABLE_PER_CLASS`) in which I define some indexes like so :

```
@Table(name = "OPERATION", indexes = {
    @Index(name = "IDX_OPERATION_ADRESSE_GEO_ID", columnList = "ADRESSE_GEO_ID"),
    @Index(name = "IDX_OPERATION_TYPE_OPERATION_ID", columnList = "TYPE_OPERATION_ID")
})
```

The tables that inherit from OPERATION then obviously have their own versions of these indexes, but my problem is that they end up having too long identifiers since their names are built as the concatenation of all child table names from the inheritance path with the base index name. An example of that :

```
create index mobilisation_socialeoperation_mobilisation_socialeIDX_OPERATION_ADRESSE_GEO_ID on mobilisation_sociale (adresse_geo_id);
create index mobilisation_socialeoperation_mobilisation_socialeIDX_OPERATION_TYPE_OPERATION_ID on mobilisation_sociale (type_operation_id);
```

I would like to be able to define some kind of naming strategy, as I have seen exists for other SQL objects (tables, columns...) through `PhysicalNamingStrategy` but does not seem to apply for my use-case. But does that exist at all or am I forced to explicitly name the same indexes on every single child entity ?

Answer (score 0):

To define an index naming strategy, you can use a custom [ImplicitNamingStrategy](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy.java). You have many implementation examples, starting with the Hibernate default once like [ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.java).

#### Example

You can use this configuration

```java
public class HibernateCustomImplicitNamingStrategy extends ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl {
    public static final ImplicitNamingStrategy INSTANCE = new HibernateCustomImplicitNamingStrategy();

    @Override
    public Identifier determineIndexName(ImplicitIndexNameSource source) {
        String name = "INDEX_" + String.join("_", source.getColumnNames().stream().map(Identifier::getCanonicalName).toList());
        return new Identifier(name, Identifier.isQuoted(name));
    }
}
```

On this Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "firstColumn, secondColumn"), // Only column list is needed
})
public class MyEntity {
   ...
}
```

To get the index: `INDEX_firstColumn_secondColumn`

In your `Config.java` file, you can add this configuration with:

```java
private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", HibernateCustomImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    ...
    return prop;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    builder.scanPackages("com.my.package.")
            .addProperties(getHibernateProperties())
            .setImplicitNamingStrategy(HibernateCustomImplicitNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

#### Note

`PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` only implements `toPhysicalCatalogName, toPhysicalColumnName, toPhysicalSchemaName, toPhysicalSequenceName and toPhysicalTableName` as you can see in the [github page](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.java).

#### Doc

You can find more examples on [sodocumentation](https://sodocumentation.net/hibernate/topic/3051/custom-naming-strategy) or on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy)